# How to change User Preference Color of Viewport Object Info

Tags: customization

Preferences/Viewport/Show Object Info, View Name and Playback FPS have checkboxes to tirn ON or OFF. BUT!!! No way to CHANGE their color. How to change their color?

Comment: I just went thru every Preferences color control I could find, and nothing changed the color of that text.  Sorry, hope somebody else can answer this.

Comment: THANK YOU for doing this. A further question! (Perhaps I will post it separately). --> Is there A MAP of what each ITEM that can be changed in Preferences is called? For someone new to this Blender thing, it's like having a LIST of NAMES of the US States, and a MAP of the United States, BUT.... the NAMES on the list are not on The Map! If you hit the name on the list, the state's area lights up. But you have to do this one at a time, and you can't write on the map. So you're stuck writing things down or....WISHING there was a map WITH the States' Names on it. Is there such a BLENDER "MAP"?

Comment: I'm not sure a map is feasable -- when I was doing this I went through the Preferences color controls changing the main color to fuscia and back-to-saved-default.  A lot of them didn't change anything visible then, but some of them changed texts that were scattered around the screen and I couldn't tell how those were under the control I'd changed.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. Could add an example (JPG) of what I am talking about. But finishing a Movie for my chief Customer is upon me for the next few days. So no time at present for even a quick example. Just time enough to CRY for help from you all In-The-Know vis-a-vis Blender as frustrations are encountered. Adieu4Now. Ox